# Python get ssl certificate information getpeercert()

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, ssl

I want to get the informations of a ssl certificate from a domain name.
By using the following code I get wired responses. The code :

```
import ssl
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(1)
wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
try:
    wrappedSocket.connect(('www.google.com', 443))
except:
    response = False
else:
    der_cert = wrappedSocket.getpeercert(False)
    der_cert_bin = wrappedSocket.getpeercert(True)
    print(der_cert)
    print(der_cert_bin)
    pem_cert = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(wrappedSocket.getpeercert(True))
    print(pem_cert)
wrappedSocket.close()
```

This code display :

```
{}
b'0\x82\x04v0\x82\x03^\xa0\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\x08\x19\xab\x97n|\x13q\xc20\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x05\x05\x000I1\x0b0\t\x06\x03U\x04\x06\x13\x02US1\x130\x11\x06\x03U\x04\n\x13\nGoogle Inc1%0#\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x13\x1cGoogle Internet Authority G20\x1e\x17\r150618085256Z\x17\r150916000000Z0h1\x0b0\t\x06\x03U\x04\x06\x13\x02US1\x130\x11\x06\x03U\x04\x08\x0c\nCalifornia1\x160\x14\x06\x03U\x04\x07\x0c\rMountain View1\x130\x11\x06\x03U\x04\n\x0c\nGoogle Inc1\x170\x15\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x0c\x0ewww.google.com0\x82\x01"0\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x01\x05\x00\x03\x82\x01\x0f\x000\x82\x01\n\x02\x82\x01\x01\x00\xca\xa9\\\x03\xb4\x07g\xb4\x87b\xeb\xf6\xd3\xc7,\xeb\ta\x07j\xaa\xab\xf80,\xd3\xbc9:p%-D\xe9\x94\xb4\xac\x12\x84P$\nUV\x15\xe3\r\xb8,\xb1[<\xc6\xf6\x8c\xf1\x8f\xbb\xfc\xc3\xec\x9f!\xee\xc4\xc9\xa4\xfc/\x8b\x02\xeb\xce\xa5\xc5\xb8\xc9[N3\xeet\x91\\\xf7\x1e\xd6\xf7|\xde\xd0\xd1\x11\xeal\xc5\r\x8c\x0b\x8c\xb4/\x8a\xc1\xbb>\x1e\xa1,\x1d01\xc1k\xdc\xca\x9b\xebH-\xa9\x19\xfc\xff\x81<\xb8\xefm\xf0\x8b\x91\x02\xf9\xe9\x07(\'\xed\xe6\x98|4\xe7\xef\x9c\xea;\x13\xcf1\xaa\xe3}\x96\x95?\xef]\x1f\x86\xc5,\xed\xbf K9j \xaad6\xf2\x10G\xcdY\x9c\xd0\x89\xeb\xc1\x11\xc3\xa5\xd5\xac\x17)\xf7\xff\x01\x9d\xa5\xd1\x1aN\xc1[\xa8\xd3L\xb1\x8b\xa7`\xac\x12\xc2\xcf\xc6RF\x88\x02\x8f4\x1ak1\xad\xeeom}\x1d"\xdc\x84~\xe2\x9d\xfe\xf2\xd9\r\xa0JH\xd6>3.\xb6J\xd4\xde\xa1X\xd5\x9c\x9b\xc3\xb8\xab\x02\x03\x01\x00\x01\xa3\x82\x01A0\x82\x01=0\x1d\x06\x03U\x1d%\x04\x160\x14\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x07\x03\x01\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x07\x03\x020\x19\x06\x03U\x1d\x11\x04\x120\x10\x82\x0ewww.google.com0h\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x07\x01\x01\x04\\0Z0+\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x070\x02\x86\x1fhttp://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt0+\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x070\x01\x86\x1fhttp://clients1.google.com/ocsp0\x1d\x06\x03U\x1d\x0e\x04\x16\x04\x14\x14\xd9\xa1\xe1\x91@$\xf3\x03\xf1\xd0\xfaIg\x11R\xe4 hT0\x0c\x06\x03U\x1d\x13\x01\x01\xff\x04\x020\x000\x1f\x06\x03U\x1d#\x04\x180\x16\x80\x14J\xdd\x06\x16\x1b\xbc\xf6h\xb5v\xf5\x81\xb6\xbbb\x1a\xbaZ\x81/0\x17\x06\x03U\x1d \x04\x100\x0e0\x0c\x06\n+\x06\x01\x04\x01\xd6y\x02\x05\x0100\x06\x03U\x1d\x1f\x04)0\'0%\xa0#\xa0!\x86\x1fhttp://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl0\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x05\x05\x00\x03\x82\x01\x01\x00q]\x07r\x9e\x9b\xc1\xb0\xe7\xb7aV\xd9M%\xdf\xa4\x9c\xfd\xbc\x10\xc1,!8\xc2\xe2\x81f\x87\xf6\xc9\x95\x14\xe8\x99@\xb8\x97Xh\x9d\\\xd6\xe9ZVDQ\\o\x9aXD\xfd\x15\xead<@U!\xc2\x84\x14&\x91\xdb\x85/Ek\xdc\x80\xc4\xf4\xd9\xe0\x00\xca\xbb=\x0f\xcd5\xd0.\xbb\xd3 4\xab\xfa\xec\xe9]\x040\xfc\xe8\xea\xee\xe6*\xe8\xf5\x8e\xf8\x91\x0b\xba\xf92\x02\xe6\x04<V\xac^\x9a\x95\xa3;\t\xd8\x8b\n\x8ab\xf3\x8b\x91\xe3\x87,\x85\xf3\xad3?x\x8d\xc6N\xdcR\xcd\xb9\x16f\xab\xc6\xa5V\xe5\xb2Kqv\xba\xd8\xb2\xf8g\xb7\x1a\xd7+m\xe1s\x0f\xdb\x8f/\x08\x07\xd1Y*[\x8aP\x8c\x01p\xa8\xb9/\x98\x1f\xd2y\xef\xf9\x8fX\x19<jY\xa5\x85\xb5(\xcd1\x9c\xff\x1b\xe2j62+*\xc3\x9b\x81\xe5:\xa2\x82*m\xb53\x00\x88\x0e\x08t\x99\xce\x91]DRg\xf3\xacH\xd1\x92D\x95oG;9\x95\x11\x1d\xde9'
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Do you know why the first print display only **{}** ?

The documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert) indicate it's empty because certificate is not valid.
In this case, why the two following print display an non-empty certificate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[Python.Docs]: SSLSocket.getpeercert(binary_form=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert) (**emphasis** is mine):

> If the `binary_form` parameter is [False](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#False), and a certificate was received from the peer, this method returns a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) instance. **If the certificate was not validated, the dict is empty**. If the certificate was validated, it returns a dict with several keys, amongst them `subject` (the principal for which the certificate was issued) and `issuer` (the principal issuing the certificate). If a certificate contains an instance of the *Subject Alternative Name* extension (see [RFC 3280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280.html)), there will also be a `subjectAltName` key in the dictionary.

If you want to validate the certificate you must pass **`cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED`** to ***ssl.wrap_socket*** (*ssl.wrap_socket(sock, keyfile=None, certfile=None, server_side=False, cert_reqs=CERT_NONE, ssl_version=PROTOCOL_TLS, ca_certs=None, do_handshake_on_connect=True, suppress_ragged_eofs=True, ciphers=None)*):

As you see by default it passes ***CERT_NONE***, which doesn't validate the peer certificate, therefore you get an empty *dict*.